# What do you call someone who is a fan of jets?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone is a fan of British culture we call them an Anglophile. French culture, Francophile. Batrachophile, fan of frogs and other amphibians. Astrophile, fan of stars and astronomy.

Is there a similar term for people who love jets? Or aviation in general? Jetophile seems awkward.

Comment: *Fanjet* is already taken :-)

Comment: Giants fans call them all sorts of things.

Comment: A turbine, perhaps?

Comment: If you see a pattern, it's that -phile is from Greek, and the preference is to find a Greek root to use for the first half, rather than "Frogophile" or "Britophile."

Comment: @AndyBonner what's the Greek word for "jet" ? 

Comment: This is certainly more specific than what you're looking for, but some "jet lovers" are ["plane spotters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_spotting). I'm sure that Justin's answer is closer to what you mean.

Comment: A "New Yorker." :)

Comment: I can't find a suitable definitive reference, but the self-applied term is typically "avgeek".

Comment: A jet-enthusiast?

Comment: I would like to call these people _airheads_ though _airhead_ emphatically does not have that meaning. Yet.

Comment: Please clarify whether this is about "jets", or as most Answers and Comments assume, "planes"

Car-lovers being "petrol-heads" or "piston-heads" suggests you might try simple "jet-heads"… the more so since "piston-heads" should be extendable to cover older planes, as well as cars.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "jets" is in the title. I don't see how it could be ambiguous.

Comment: @jcollum Good for you. If you'd like to clarify, please clarify. If you'd like to argue, please go to Chat.

Comment: Don't get salty and passive aggressive just because I clarified @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: @jcollum Don't you get aggressive. Do please recognise that you did not clarify, and it remains true that most Answers and Comments assumed "jets" meant "planes".

That I think they're misguided isn't the point.

That you seem to want to throw that aside seems to me to matter.

Do you care, or not?

Comment: You're the only one that raised this issue. "Good for you" is passive aggressive. I don't care about your opinion at this point since you aren't apologizing for being passive aggressive even after being called out on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you might be looking for ***aerophile***:

> **aerophile**
> <sub>noun</sub>
>
> : a lover of aviation
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aerophile))

Comment: Not sure -- that could also be a plant that needs air circulation, or a person liking fresh air. It's lacking the "plane" part. Air alone is not enough. (OMG, I missed the M-W link! That word exists! Well, I stand by my opinion, stubborn as I am ;-).)

Answer (score 3):

For a more colloquial construction, you might substitute "jet" for "rail" or "train" and come up with ***jet-spotter*** as analogous to *train-spotter*   Train wonks have been around as long as rail has existed.

Further variations on the rail theme would include (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railfan)

- railfan  --> jetfan
- rail buff or train buff --> jet buff
- trainspotter --> jetspotter
- steam-engine wonk --> jet-engine wonk
- ferroequinologist --> aluminaornithologist (okay this one is a stretch)

Or the somewhat-generic term for a person who is forever looking at trains, waiting on sidings for them to pass, making notes of engine numbers is an ***anorak*** - which is a type of warm outdoor coat/jacket that someone might wear casually in the cold, when waiting for a train to pass or a flight to land.

Comment: A fan specifically of *passenger* trains would be an Amtrak Anorak?

Comment: Plane spotting or aircraft spotting is common, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_spotting

Comment: 'Wonk' and 'buff' are rather restricted to US English. Anorak is very much British (I think Americans call the clothing item a 'parka'). In Britain, it has become associated with 'trainspotters', a sub group of 'railway enthusiasts', who are imagined to wear them while they wait at stations to write down engine numbers. Spotters are often said to be more likely to be on the autistic spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a word in its own right but lovers or enthusiasts of something are generally called [*aficionados*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado).

So, such a person would be a *jet* or *airplane* or *aviation aficionado*.

(Perhaps an aviaconado?? ;-) )

Comment: Even google can't find much for "aviaconado" yet.  How long will it be before this answer is the top match ?

Comment: @Criggie I made that up, so it should have been from the start!